# How is "sein" conjugated in this sub-sentence?

Tags: grammatical-case, subject, ellipsis

The full sentence:

"Ausschließlich harten Alkohol müsst ihr selbst mitbringen, *wenn euch danach ist*."

- How is "sein" conjugated in this sentence, and why would it be "ist" even though "euch" describes a group of people?
- What is the "ist" referring to? Is the form of "sein" even dependant on "euch" in this case?

Comment: That is an idiomatic phrase which is really hard to catch if you don't know it. Actually, the verb is _jemandem nach etwas (zumute) sein_. Also see https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zumute

Comment: Simply read it as *... if you so desire*.

Comment: the full sense will be obvious if you  mind that "ist" is not related to "euch" but to **"es"**: "Es ist mir nicht danach zumute" oder "Es macht mir nichts aus." e.g. another example in English: *It* doesn't matter.

Comment: 'ist' is referring to an ephemeral 'it', the same way as in '*it* is raining'

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach It doesn't have anything to do with idiomatic in that sense. Its a normal behaviour of third person impersonal sentences in spoken German. Die Redewendung "es ist jemandem danach" ist zwar idiomatisch, die Auslassung von "es" - worum es bei der Frage eher geht - nicht.

Comment: @Dan Yes, you are right. I thought, the omitted _zumute_ was the problem of the questioner, but actually, the real problem is the omitted expletive _es_

Comment: 3rd p sg is an old politeness form, perhaps that carried over to this 2nd p pl politeness form in circumstances where reference to an external object allows it. I'm not convinced this object always had to be "es" and it's omission here seems to be uniquely confined to expressions of the same manner (e.g. "wenn euch danach beliebt", which should be easier to search). I'm trying to see *danach* as a determiner, but can't explain it grammatically, although I would tentatively substitute "das", "wenn euch das gefällt".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The verb *ist* is 3rd person singular, which is the form that always occurs when the verb has no subject argument.

> Ist Ihnen heiß, schwindelig, schlecht?
>   *Are you hot, dizzy, sick?*

In the above example, *heiß, schwindelig, schlecht* are adjectives that occur together with a dative, i.e. *Ihnen*. Verbs never agree with a dative, so even if *Ihnen* is plural, the verb is 3rd person singular as there is no subject present. Your assumption that the form *ist* is independent of *euch* is correct.

Another example of verbs missing a subject argument is impersonal passives, where the verb occurs in the 3rd person singular as well.

> Wurde euch geholfen?
>   Ihnen wurde nicht geglaubt.

As far as meaning is concerned, you can treat

> Mir ist (nicht) nach …

as an idiom meaning

> I (don't) feel like …

The preposition *nach* can probably be explained by deriving the idiom from *zumute sein nach*.

> Ihnen war nicht nach Feiern zumute.
>   *They didn't feel like partying.*

Comment: "which is the form that always occurs when there is no subject present" Here some counter examples:
- Ja, mach das. 
- hallo wie gehts? bin heute so richtig gut gelaunt
- na dann erst mal Rewe und dann Müggelsee 
In all of this examples there is no subject and no 3d person singular form. Please correct your wording as it's confusing.

Comment: "Verbs never agree with a dative," true.  However, there are German dialects where "uns/ons" hat die Bedeutung von "wir" und "euch" die Bedeutung von "ihr".  But that's just as a fun fact.

Comment: @Dan I changed it to something more technical.

Comment: What did you change? With due respect, your answer is still somewhat missing the question, that being the subject omission in impersonal sentences, elaborating on the idiom "jemandem danach sein" instead.

Comment: @Dan You can click on the "edited yesterday" link to see what changed. – I don't see this as a case of omission. The verb has no subject argument; it then occurs in the 3rd person singular. This is what happens with impersonal passives, so it's a useful rule to learn.

Comment: I don't agree. In my opinion, the subject argument is still there - and defines the 3d person form of the verb and not something else - only it is omitted.

Answer (score 8):

> What is the "ist" referring to? Is the form of "sein" even dependant on "euch" in this case?

**ist** is corresponding with *es*:

eg: Mir **ist** nicht danach! -> **Es** ist mir nicht danach!"

(means: Ich habe keine Lust.)